# Using clearInterval to stop a function

Tags: javascript

I have a function that displays words at various speeds. The function starts OK, but I can't seem to get the code right to stop it again. 
I know I have to use clearInterval and I assume that this is to clear the var myTimer - but I can't get this to work.

Any help would be appreciated

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="wpm($numberWords,$speed)" />
<input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="stopWpm()" />
```

JS

```
var myTimer;

function wpm(numberWords,speed) {

    var input = new Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s");

    var output = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i += numberWords) {
        output.push(input.slice(i, i + numberWords).join(" "));
    }

    var i=0;
    var myTimer =setInterval(timer,speed); //1000 will run it every 1 second
    function timer() {
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = output[i];
        i++;
        if (i == output.length){
            clearInterval(myTimer);
        }
    }
}   

function stopWpm() {
    clearInterval(myTimer);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have `myTimer`; as a global var and within `wpm()` you have redeclared it try removing the `var` from `myTimer` within `wpm()` function

```
// ...
var i=0;
myTimer = setInterval(timer,speed); //1000 will run it every 1 second
function timer() {
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help - this works and I now see why! However, if I click the Start button multiple times the code will display "undefined" at the end of the loop. Is there a way to check if the function is already running?

Comment: @tomp, to check if function is already running, do next: after each call of `clearInterval(myTimer);` add code `myTimer=0;` and then you can check for function running as `if(myTimer) {/*code if function running or planned for running*/} else {/*code if function not running*/}`. And accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
I had the same problem and this worked for me:

    var operate = function () { start = setInterval( function(){
    ... 
    }
} , time ); }
    var stop = function () {  clearInterval( start ); }
    return { Start: start, Stop: stop }
    }
```

use `operate.Start()` || `operate.Stop()` to handle